# making a list of li into columns not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to split a long list of `<li>` into 3 columns with javascript, instead of CSS3 (as it's not supported in all browsers, i.e. IE). But it's not working.
Basically, I want to take every 5 or 7 or 3, whatever number, `<li>`'s and make them as columns and so on. So if I have `A B C D E F G H I J K L` in list, the 1st column should consist of `ABCDEF` and the next column will start from `GHIJKL`. I hope you see what I mean.

Javascript:

```
var colCount = 3,
        ul = $('ul'),
        li = ul.find('li'),
        liLen = li.length,
        liPerCol = Math.ceil(liLen / colCount),
        ulWrap = '<ul style="float:left;width:200px;margin-right:20px;" />',
        liSub,
        i;

for(i = 0; i < liLen; i++){
    liSub = liLen.slice(i, 4);
    liSub.wrap($(ulWrap));
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">COLUMN 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">col 1.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Apsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Aonor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Aomsdomsdio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Asdijnd oasd</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Awrom</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Aoidn iojd</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Apyrie sdij</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Asddewdwe</a></li>    
  <li><a href="#">Apsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Aonor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Aomsdomsdio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Asdijnd oasd</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Awrom</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Aoidn iojd</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Apyrie sdij</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Last entry col 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please I need your assistance.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/97sJ6/1/

This splits the li's up into three columns.

```
var li = $('li'),
    len = li.length,
    col_len = 3,
    num_cols = Math.floor(len/col_len),
    j = 0;

li.each(function(i) {
    if (i % num_cols == 0 && j < col_len) {
        j++;
        $('body').append('<ul style="float:left;width:200px;margin-right:20px;" id="divider' + j + '"/>');          
    }
   if (j == col_len+1) j--;
   $(this).appendTo('#divider' + j);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try in css 2.1, give float:left and specify some width for all li. i hope

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/RXQgn/1/

Comment: No, this is not what I'm looking for. In your solution the `<li>` are floated side by side. What I want is that the list should split after, for example, every 5 `<li>`, then create a new column for the next 5 `<li>` and so on...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say thanks for your effort. So do you see what I mean and have you got another solution?